# maven deploy:deploy-file working but maven deploy not working

Tags: java, maven, deployment, artifactory, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to deploy maven artifacts into Artifactory repository using command : maven deploy .

I followed instructions from Maven documentation and JFrog :

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-DeployingArtifactsThroughArtifactory

For the moment, maven deploy:deploy-file works.

I assume credentials stored in settings.xml and corresponding repository id are correct.

But when running maven deploy I got the error :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-app: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.mvn.deployment:my-app:jar:1.0-20190518.184733-1 from/to snapshots

Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Do you have any idea why would deploy-file work and deploy is not working ?

Thanks

maven deploy:deploy-file working :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=REPO_URL \
                      -DrepositoryId="snapshots" \
                      -Dfile=PATH_TO_JAR \
                      -DgroupId="Project" \
                      -DartifactId="test-project" \
                      -Dversion="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

While mvn deploy gives an error :

```
mvn deploy

ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-
plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-app: Failed to deploy 
artifacts: Could not transfer artifact 
com.mvn.deployment:my-app:jar:1.0-20190518.184733-1 from/to snapshots

Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

**UPDATE :**

I did some tests using different versions of maven and found the problem appears from version 3.5.0, the mvn deploy command works on maven 3.3.9 and I think it's related to new version of maven-wagon as in version 3.5.0 they upgraded Maven Wagon from 2.10 to 2.12.

By adding this config to my pom.xml *mvn deploy* works :

```
  <extension>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
     <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
     <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
```

Comment: You do not permission to upload the artifact in Artifactory. You have to get proper credential and authorization to upload

Comment: I think I have the right permissions, by using maven deploy:deploy-file I uploaded a jar file successfully.

Comment: So now it is working for you. If you want , you update the Answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, maven deploy:deploy-file is working, maven deploy doesn't work.

Comment: How are you exactly calling `deploy:deploy-file`?

Comment: @khmarbaise : I updated the question with deploy-file parameters.

Comment: Your settings.xml file does not correctly contain your credentials to deploy to the appropriate repository ...

Comment: I added an update to the question, by changing the version of Maven Wagon I got it working. You think that there was a change in the way credentials are set going from Maven Wagon 2.10 to 2.12 ? I looked into the changelogs and found nothing. May be I missed something.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Seems, `mvn deploy` command has no right credentials and gives 401 response code, but settings.xml file correct and `mvn deploy:deploy-file` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests using different versions of maven and found the problem appears from version 3.5.0, the mvn deploy command works on maven 3.3.9 and I think it's related to new version of maven-wagon as in version 3.5.0 they upgraded Maven Wagon from 2.10 to 2.12.

By adding this config to my pom.xml mvn deploy works :

```
<build>
     <plugins>
         <!-- It is a good idea to also set the maven-deploy-plugin version here -->
     </plugins>
     <extensions>
         <extension>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
             <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
             <version>2.10</version>
         </extension>
     </extension>
</build>
```

Thanks [Adrien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965134/adrien) for the maven-deploy-plugin version advice.

Comment: Hi +Hamza can you help me in a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, you had the correct answer. `mvn deploy:deploy` doesn't use the credentials, even if correctly specified in the settings.xml, to upload to the repository, producing a `Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact: Failed to transfer file xyz.jar with status code 401` error.

- `mvn deploy:deploy-file` works,
- `mvn deploy:deploy` doesn't work: It doesn't use the user/password from settings.xml to upload to the repository.

Your solution is correct:

```
<build>
     <plugins>
         <!-- It is a good idea to also set the maven-deploy-plugin version here -->
     </plugins>
     <extensions>
         <extension>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
             <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
             <version>2.10</version>
         </extension>
     </extension>
</build>
```

This answer was based on work from [Hamza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599558/hamza).

Comment: I've updated your post to indicate who you are referring to ("you" and "your") and to provide attribution for the work. Feel free to amend if I got it wrong. There's no need to add further apologies - material reuse (with attribution) is allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I found another reason (Maven 3.3.3 and 3.3.9): building with `mvn clean install deploy` failed with this same error (`Forbbiden...`) while `mvn deploy` worked. I simply removed the redundant `install` phase because it will execute anyway as part of `deploy`phase.

PS: Yes I know, `install` shouldn't be there, but that is not the point, it is just interesting how it came up with a completely unrelated error message.